# C++11 : Is it possible to give fixed-template-parameted template to varidic-template-template-parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer

(Yes, the title is so weird thanks to my *poor* English; I hope someone can improve it.)

Answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059219/template-deduction-fails-for-stdmap-as-template-parameter), I found that this code works:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> class A { };
template <template <typename...> class U> class B { };

int main()
{
    B<A> it_works;
}
```

..although `template <typename...> class` and `template <typename, typename> class` aren't equal.

I tried to figure out why it is possible and watch [temp.param] of [N3337 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), but I can't find anything. How is it possible?

Comment: The same reason you can do `template<typename... Ts> void foo();` and then do `foo<int>();`, or `foo<char, double>();`, or whatever else you want. If you're looking for standard text, a lot of the stuff under Variadic Templates: *A template parameter pack is a template parameter that accepts zero or more template arguments*

Comment: Oh, your comment is actually an answer >o<

Comment: @ikh: Yes, and now it's a proper answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[temp.arg.template] describes how template template arguments are matched with the corresponding parameter. In particular, C++11 14.3.3/3 says

> When P’s *template-parameter-list* contains a template parameter pack, the template parameter pack will match zero or more template parameters or template parameter packs in the *template-parameter-list* of A with the same type and form as the template parameter pack in P

where P is the parameter (`U` in your example), and A the argument (`A` in your example). So your example, with only a parameter pack, will match a template with any number of type parameters.

Comment: Umm. I cannot decide to select your answer or Angew's answer.... but I'm finally going to accept yours due to its simplicity. (however I'm still unwilling to select *only* one of them >o<)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible to do so. C++ 11 14.3.3/3 specifically allows it, and provides an example.

> 3 A *template-argument* matches a template *template-parameter* (call it `P`) when each of the template parameters
>   in the *template-parameter-list* of the *template-argument*’s corresponding class template or alias template (call
>   it `A`) matches the corresponding template parameter in the *template-parameter-list* of `P`. **When `P`’s *template-parameter-list* contains a template parameter pack (14.5.3), the template parameter pack will match zero
>   or more template parameters or template parameter packs in the *template-parameter-list* of `A` with the
>   same type and form as the template parameter pack in `P` (ignoring whether those template parameters are
>   template parameter packs)** [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template <class T> struct eval;
>
> template <template <class, class...> class TT, class T1, class... Rest>
> struct eval<TT<T1, Rest...>> { };
>
> template <class T1> struct A;
> template <class T1, class T2> struct B;
> template <int N> struct C;
> template <class T1, int N> struct D;
> template <class T1, class T2, int N = 17> struct E;
>
> eval<A<int>> eA; // OK: matches partial specialization of eval
> eval<B<int, float>> eB; // OK: matches partial specialization of eval
> eval<C<17>> eC; // error: C does not match TT in partial specialization
> eval<D<int, 17>> eD; // error: D does not match TT in partial specialization
> eval<E<int, float>> eE; // error: E does not match TT in partial specialization
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

(Emphasis mine)